# jQuery UI widget factory: how to reference widget instance using 'this' inside a options?

Tags: jquery-ui-widget-factory, jquery-ui-widget

I have the following code snippet:

```
$.widget("tj.commonCoordinator", {
    options: {
        "obx_type": "common_obx",
        "obx_callbacks": {
            request_modify: function(event, ui) {
                this._loadentries();
            },
        }
    },

    _loadentries: function(){}
});
```

Note that inside the options object, there is a `request_modify` anonymous function. Inside that function I'm using `this` to reference the currently initiated widget instance, but failed. In this broken code the `this` references to the `window` as it is just an anonymous function.

What is the best way to make `this` inside a `options` object of the `Widget` factory prototype reference correctly to the widget instance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method to do this:

```
$.proxy(this._loadentries, this)
```